# Creating a Matrix of Floats to do Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, matrix, regression, polynomial-math

I'm trying to do a polynomial regression of csv file I have (or any other csv file). I am not sure how to build a matrix that contains the data set I have. Here is the current code I have.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np
import csv
from math import *

f=open("data_setshort.csv", "r")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
xval = []
yval = []
polyreg = []

for row in csv_f:
    xval.append(row[0])
    yval.append(row[1])

f.close()

x = np.array(xval)
y = np.array(yval)
xlist = [float(i) for i in x]
ylist = [float(i) for i in y]

print xlist
print ylist

def poly_fit(x,y):
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        M = np.matrix(x[i],y[i])
    return M

Matrix = poly_fit(xlist,ylist)

print Matrix
```

The `poly_fit(x,y)` is the function I am trying to build to do the polynomial regression.

Comment: It depends on the input data. How is it the csv file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood exactly what you're trying to do, but if it's fitting a polynomial from continuous x and y values, then this will do it:

```
import numpy as np


xi = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, 30)
ni = np.random.uniform(0, .4, 30)

coefficients = np.polyfit(xi, ni, 3)
print coefficients
```

Then, to use it to generate y values given new x values:

```
new_x = 2.5
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
new_y = polynomial(new_x)
```